# Error when installing PyDev plugin for Eclipse

Tags: python, eclipse, installation, pydev

When trying to install PyDev on eclipse I get the following error message:

```
An error occurred while collecting items to be installed session context was: (profile=epp.package.jee, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Collect, operand=, action=).
Unable to read repository at http://pydev.org/updates/plugins/org.python.pydev_2.6.0.2012062818.jar.
Read timed out
Unable to read repository at http://pydev.org/updates/plugins/org.python.pydev.jython_2.6.0.2012062818.jar.
Read timed out
```

I don't know what that means, can someone elaborate please?
Thanks.

Comment: I have experienced this myself, it appears to mean that the server is busy.  Try again later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just that Eclipse can't reach the site to fetch that JAR. You can check it manually by entering the name into the browser address bar:

http://pydev.org/updates/plugins/org.python.pydev_2.6.0.2012062818.jar

Possible causes:

- server overload
- DNS failure
- company firewall refusing to download (had this happen to me)
- connectivity problems

Comment: So I can take these JARs and put them in my directory manually?

Comment: Possibly, but I don't think so. I believe there are some maintenance tasks that Eclipse has to perform after downloading to complete the installation.

Comment: Okey, I got it to work... eventually, I just kept trying every now and then all day. Thanks for you help. :)